# How read all codes by linq query and save in to single collection

Tags: c#, linq

I want to read all AuthRole code from RoleAmpLabelAdded in single linq query in one collection. i am writing below query to extract the data then doing string join.currently. I am doing as below.
Please suggest me some efficient solution

```
 string strRoleCodesA = string.Join(",", request.ApplicationsAccess.CategoryAccessType
                                                           .SelectMany(c => c.BasicApplications.RoleAmpLabelAdded
                                                           .Select(t => t.AuthRoleCode)));

                          string  strRoleCodesB = string.Join(",", request.ApplicationsAccess.CategoryAccessType
                                                     .SelectMany(c => c.RegualrApplications.RoleAmpLabelAdded
                                                     .Select(t => t.AuthRoleCode)));

                            string strRoleCodesC = string.Join(",", request.ApplicationsAccess.CategoryAccessType
                                                       .SelectMany(c => c.OptionalSpecialApplications.RoleAmpLabelAdded
                                                       .Select(t => t.AuthRoleCode)));

                            strRoleCodesD = string.Concat(strRoleCodesA, strRoleCodesB, strRoleCodesC);
```

I dont want to the above string join. Below is the class structure of above code.

```
    public partial class ApplicationsAccess
{
    [JsonProperty("categoryAccessType")]
    public List<CategoryAccessTypeAMP> CategoryAccessType { get; set; }
}

public partial class CategoryAccessTypeAMP
{
    [JsonProperty("categoryCode")]
    public string CategoryCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("basicApplications")]
    public Applications BasicApplications { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("regualrApplications")]
    public Applications RegualrApplications { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("optionalSpecialApplications")]
    public Applications OptionalSpecialApplications { get; set; }
}

public partial class Applications
{
    [JsonProperty("applictaionType")]
    public string ApplictaionType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("roleAmpLabelAdded")]
    public List<RoleAmpLabels> RoleAmpLabelAdded { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("roleAmpLabelRemoved")]
    public List<RoleAmpLabels> RoleAmpLabelRemoved { get; set; }
}

public partial class RoleAmpLabels
{
    [JsonProperty("roleAMPLabel")]
    public string RoleAmpLabelRoleAmpLabel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("authRoleCode")]
    public string AuthRoleCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("authRoleName")]
    public string AuthRoleName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("applications")]
    public List<Applications> Applications { get; set; }
}

public partial class Applications
{
    [JsonProperty("appId")]
    public string AppId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("appCode")]
    public string AppCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("appName")]
    public string AppName { get; set; }
}
```

The classes are loaded from this JSON string :

```
{
  "applicationsAccess": {
    "categoryAccessType": [
      {
        "categoryCode": "string",
        "basicApplications": {
          "applictaionType": "string",
          "roleAmpLabelAdded": [
            {
              "roleAMPLabel": "string",
              "authRoleCode": "string",
              "authRoleName": "string",
              "applications": [
                {
                  "appId": "string",
                  "appCode": "string",
                  "appName": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "roleAmpLabelRemoved": [
            {
              "roleAMPLabel": "string",
              "authRoleCode": "string",
              "authRoleName": "string",
              "applications": [
                {
                  "appId": "string",
                  "appCode": "string",
                  "appName": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "regualrApplications": {
          "applictaionType": "string",
          "roleAmpLabelAdded": [
            {
              "roleAMPLabel": "string",
              "authRoleCode": "string",
              "authRoleName": "string",
              "applications": [
                {
                  "appId": "string",
                  "appCode": "string",
                  "appName": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "roleAmpLabelRemoved": [
            {
              "roleAMPLabel": "string",
              "authRoleCode": "string",
              "authRoleName": "string",
              "applications": [
                {
                  "appId": "string",
                  "appCode": "string",
                  "appName": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "optionalSpecialApplications": {
          "applictaionType": "optionalSpecialApplications",
          "roleAmpLabelAdded": [
            {
              "roleAMPLabel": "string",
              "authRoleCode": "string",
              "authRoleName": "string",
              "applications": [
                {
                  "appId": "string",
                  "appCode": "string",
                  "appName": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "roleAmpLabelRemoved": [
            {
              "roleAMPLabel": "string",
              "authRoleCode": "string",
              "authRoleName": "string",
              "applications": [
                {
                  "appId": "string",
                  "appCode": "string",
                  "appName": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can combine multiple Enumerables with `Union` too, removing the need for three `String.Join` and one concatenation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos union removes duplicates, this way does not. I believe it's more a `Concat` than a `Union`

Comment: So, a RoleAmpLabels has an Applications has a RoleAmpLabels has an Applications... How deep does it go?

Comment: @CaiusJard one can use `Concat` instead of `Union`. The recursive relation though is the real problem. It can be solved with an iterator method, but this is definitely not as simple as writing a single LINQ query

Comment: Since the classes come from a JSON string, one could use `JObject.Parse` or `JArray.Parse` to parse the entire string and use JSON Path to retrieve all `AuthRoleCode` elements, eg `o.SelectToken("$..authRolecode")`

Comment: In response to the latest edit, I'm not seeing why your C# classes are self referencing. The bottom `class Applications` would be better off called `ApplicationDetail`, `RoleAmpDetail.Applications` instead being a `public List<ApplicationDetail> ApplicationDetails { get; set; }` and none of these classes being partial. There seems to be only one application detail (my name) per roleamplabel (in your example data) so i'm not even sure why it's a json array

Answer (score 2):

So if you do this:

```
request.ApplicationsAccess.CategoryAccessType
  .SelectMany(c => new[] { c.BasicApplications, c.RegualrApplications, c.OptionalSpecialApplications})
```

SelectMany will flatten the "array of Applications" into a single list of all the Applications, with their sublists of List

Then you add this:

```
  .SelectMany(a => a.RoleAmpLabelAdded)
```

It gets you all the RoleAmpLabels in all the RoleAmpLabels lists in all the applications, flattened into a single list of RoleAmpLabels, so you can then do:

```
  .Select(r => r.AuthRoleCode)
```

Which is an `IEnumerable<string>` that can be fed straight into `string.Join`
.Select(t => t.AuthRoleCode)));

---

It would make things easier to reason if you'd change your class names to follow the C# convention of being singular and your property names to be plural (if they're a collection).

```
List<RoleAmpLabels> RoleAmpLabelAdded
```

Is better written as one of:

```
List<RoleAmpLabel> RoleAmpLabelsAdded
List<RoleAmpLabel> AddedRoleAmpLabels //my preference
```

If you make a class that is a collection, whose sole purpose is to be a collection, then append "Collection" to it, like DataRowCollection. If you have a regular class that happens to have multiples of some other class, then name the property plural

```
Dealership{
  List<Car> CarsForSale
  List<Car> CarsInForRepair
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the classes come from a JSON string, one could use `JObject.Parse` to parse the entire string and use JSON Path to retrieve all AuthRoleCode elements, eg :

```
var o=JObject.Parse(json);
var codes=o.SelectTokens("$..authRoleCode").Select(s=>(string)s).ToArray();
```

The cast is needed to extract the values of the JToken objects returned by `SelectToken`.

This can be converted to a comma-separated list with `String.Join()`, eg ;

```
var codes=o.SelectTokens("$..authRoleCode");
var csv=String.Join(",",codes);
```

The cast isn't needed in this case, as `String.Join` calls the `ToString()` method of each element.

Running this code with the question's JSON returns :

```
string,string,string,string,string,string
```